# SAXParseException: Unexpected token when trying to parse remote XML on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser, saxparseexception

I am trying to parse an XML from the internet and display some of its data in a simple TextView. Here is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        try {

            String UTF8 = "utf-8";
            URL url = new URL("http://pollenapps.com/AllergyAlertWebSVC/api/1.0/Forecast/ForecastForZipCode?Zipcode=02145&Affiliateid=9642&AppID=2.1.0&uid=6693636764.xml");
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            //InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            //InputStream in = new URL("http://pollenapps.com/AllergyAlertWebSVC/api/1.0/Forecast/ForecastForZipCode?Zipcode=02145&Affiliateid=9642&AppID=2.1.0&uid=6693636764.xml").openStream();
            //getAssets().open("file.xml");
            InputStream in = url.openStream();

            //InputStream is2 = new FileInputStream(file);

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            //Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8")));
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(in, "UTF-8");
            //Document doc = dBuilder.parse(in);

            Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
            element.normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("allergyForecast");

            for (int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nList.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element2 = (Element) node;
                    tv1.setText(getValue("Day0", element2));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    }

    private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
        NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node node = nodeList.item(0);
        return node.getNodeValue();
    }
}
```

This code works as intended when I run it on a local file (one of those commended out InputStreams is for a local file) but when I try to run it on the XML file from the internet, I get the following error:

```
07-04 12:58:06.550 23289-23289/mystikos.pollentest W/System.err: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT {"allergyForecas...@1:990 in java.io.InputStreamReader@2ff0997)
```

Based on some research it seems like the parser can't tell what type of encoding the XML file has, so I need to define it. However, I am not sure how to define it here... my attempts at defining "UTF-8" encoding are visible in commented out lines, but those did not work. Any suggestions?

XML: http://pollenapps.com/AllergyAlertWebSVC/api/1.0/Forecast/ForecastForZipCode?Zipcode=02145&Affiliateid=9642&AppID=2.1.0&uid=6693636764.xml

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data that You get in response is in json, not in xml. Prefix `.xml` in your url is not take data in xml when you get inputStream from UrlOpenConnection, and can be removed.
To see the data that you got:

```
        String data = "";
        while (in.available() > 0)
            data += (char)in.read();
        System.out.println(data);
```

Result is : {"allergyForecast":{"Day0":4.1,"Day1":3.7,"Day2":4.6,"Day3":1.4,"Day4":2.9," ... }

To parse date you can use Gson for example. Code snippet to parse element:

```
        JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(new InputStreamReader(in));
     // or from readed from inputStream string:
     // JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(data);
        JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
        jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("allergyForecast");
```

And than you can get required values from jsonObject.
Or you can check API how to get response in xml if you need only xml.